# Printing fields only related to foreignkey in django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am trying to print only entries associated with the foreignkey of my models. I have a series of lists and I want to print the list name and all the items that fall under that list. My current issue is that there is a div generating for each list, which is good, but every single item associated with every list is printing out inside of the div as well, not just the items associated with the listname.

## Views

```
def control_panel(request, username):

    context = RequestContext(request)
    if username == request.user.username:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)

            lists = request.user.newlist_set.all()

            listitems = request.user.newlistitem_set.all().filter(list_name = lists)

            return render_to_response('controlpanel.html', {'lists': lists,'listitems':listitems,}, context)
        else:
            return render_to_response('login.html', {}, context)
    else:
        return render_to_response('controlpanel.html', {}, context)
```

## Models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class newlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/', default = "")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name

class newlistitem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    list_name = models.ForeignKey(newlist)
    list_item = models.CharField(max_length = 200)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_item
```

## HTML

```
            {% for lista in lists %} <!-- This is a call to the lists that exist for eaach model taht s instantiates -->

                    <div id = "indivlistitem">


                        <b>{{lista}}</b><br> <!-- This is the title of each list that is rendered to the HTML -->

                        {% for eachlistitem in listitems %}

                            {{eachlistitem}}

                        {%endfor%}

                    </div>

                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you don't need your listitems in your context, having the newlists should suffice. You have access to queries in template as well, so you can access foreign key directly in templates. Like this:

```
{% for eachlistitem in lista.newlistitem_set.all %}
```

.
This'll give you all listitems that have current lista as list_name

Comment: I believe this is what I am going for, but your code snippet fails to print anything at all.

Comment: hum, I didn't put the proper model name. It should be lista.newlistitem_set.all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `listitems` definition in your models.py.  Specifically, you define `lists` as all of the lists related to a given user, which is good, but then define `listitems` as every listitem related to every list (`filter(list_name=lists`) related to that user, which is bad.

Since request contexts are just python dictionaries, and can be nested, I would do something like the following:

```
def control_panel(request, username):

    context = RequestContext(request)
    if username == request.user.username:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)

            lists = request.user.newlist_set.all()

            listitems = {}
            for list in lists:
                listitems[list.list_name] = request.user.newlistitem_set.filter(list_name=list)

            return render_to_response('controlpanel.html', {'lists': lists,'listitems':listitems,}, context)
        else:
            return render_to_response('login.html', {}, context)
    else:
        return render_to_response('controlpanel.html', {}, context)
```

This will create a dictionary with one entry per list, that you can then render in the template:

```
        {% for lista in lists %} <!-- This is a call to the lists that exist for eaach model taht s instantiates -->

                <div id = "indivlistitem">


                    <b>{{lista}}</b><br> <!-- This is the title of each list that is rendered to the HTML -->

                    {% for eachlistitem in listitems.{{lista.list_name}} %}

                        {{eachlistitem}}

                    {%endfor%}

                </div>

            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I get the following: Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'list_name'

Comment: Sorry, that all() is supposed to be filter.  Updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, unfortunately Julien Grégoire fixed the issue nicely.

Comment: Ah, filter, that would make a lot more sense, thank you!